# Issue with iteration "Uncaught Error: coordinates is required"

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I am using mapbox and turf.js to allow users to draw a polygon on the map and then in return get the perimeter distance. I am able to get it to do the function I want and I am receiving/displaying the correct measurements, but now I get "Uncaught Error: coordinates is required". I think that it is where I am trying to create a variable to iterate through the coordinates (var to and var from), but I haven't found a solution to fix it.

```
function measurements(e) {
  var data = draw.getAll();
  var answer = document.getElementById('calculated-perimeter');
  if (data.features.length > 0) {
    var coordinates = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
    var calc_distances = []
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i<coordinates.length; i++){
      var from = turf.point(coordinates[i]);
      var to = turf.point(coordinates[i+1]);
      var options = {units: 'kilometers'};
      var distance = turf.distance(from, to ,options);
      calc_distances.push(distance);
      console.log(calc_distances);
      var perimeter = calc_distances.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      var strg_per = perimeter.toString();
      var strg_per = Math.round(strg_per * 1000)
      answer.innerHTML ='<p><strong>' + strg_per + '</strong></p><p>meters</p>';} 
  } else {
    answer.innerHTML = '';
    if (e.type !== 'draw.delete')
    alert('Use the draw tools to draw a polygon!');
  }
}

-------------------------------

EDIT : here is the full stack trace:

turf.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: coordinates is required
    at Object.r [as point] (turf.min.js:1)
    at r.measurements ((index):173)
    at r.zt.fire (evented.js:119)
    at r.i.fire (setup.js:52)
    at q.Jt.onStop (draw_polygon.js:81)
    at Object.stop (object_to_mode.js:57)
    at Object.stop (mode_handler.js:57)
    at Object.c [as changeMode] (events.js:169)
    at q.changeMode (mode_interface_accessors.js:151)
    at q.Jt.onKeyUp (draw_polygon.js:66)
```

Comment: Please paste the full stack trace.

Comment: @Konowy I edited and added it in above

Answer (score 1):

The combination of these two lines looks wrong:

```
for (i = 0; i<coordinates.length; i++){

...


var to = turf.point(coordinates[i+1]);`
```

You will be calling `turf.point(undefined)`.

Probably that first line should be:

```
for (i = 0; i<coordinates.length - 1; i++){
```